# C: unable to print from file

Tags: c, printf, unistd.h

So I have this project where I need to open a file and print the contents in C, but I have to use unix system calls. However I'm not to clear as to why nothing prints.  I try to run the code, but it seems to skip straight to the close error.  I'm aware I need unistd.h, I already have that included.

```
#define MAXBUF 4096
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
int x = 0, y, z = 1, a;         //x: Counter, Y:int for open, z:another counter, a:int for read
char buff[MAXBUF];              //set buffer size
int fe,fn,ft;                   //fe = found E, fn = found n, ft = found T
if((y = open( argv[2], O_RDONLY )) == -1){
    errHandler("Couldn't open ", argv[2]);
    }
            .
            .
            .

if(fn  == 1){                                   //if fn returned true
    printf("%d ", z++);
    }

while( ( a = read( y, buff, MAXBUF ) ) > 0 ){           

    if ( buff == '\n' && fe && fn )        //<--
        printf("$\n%4d:  ", z++ );
    else if ( buff == '\n' && fe )
        printf("\n");                      //Flags for various options
    else if ( buff == '\t' && ft )         
        printf("^T");
    else if ( buff == '\n' && fn )
        printf("\n%4d:  ", z++ );          //<--
    else
        printf("%c", buff);
}
close(y);
if ( close( y ) == -1)
    printf("Unable to close file");
return 0;
}
```

edit:  Here's the declarations.  The '.' are skipping the code that's just setting the flags.

Comment: You closed the file twice. You should remove the first close instance.

Comment: What is `buff`?  The type signature for `read` requires it to be a `void*`, but you're comparing it against `char`s.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can see some possible problems in your code (such as pointed out by jwodder) but we can't give a definitive answer unless you show all the relevant code in an MCVE. For example, the logic relies on variable values that you have not shown (`fe`, `fn`, `ft`, etc).

Comment: @jwodder Well, the type signature requires it to be some kind of pointer, typically `char *`.

Comment: Tab (`'\t'`) is `^I`, not `^T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your:

```
if ( buff == '\n' && fe && fn )        //<--
```

I assume you want to check if an empty line was read by checking it against the newline character. However, `buff` is not the character; it is a pointer to were all the characters read are stored. To check if the first character of `buff` is the newline character, use:

```
if ( *buff == '\n' && fe && fn )        //<--
```

The `*` dereferences the pointer and gives you the first character. Same for your other checks. If these checks fail, then print the line:

```
else
    printf("%s", buff);
```

Note the formatting character `%s`, not `%c`, to print a string (the buffer) instead of a single character.

Comment: Given the original code, I can see how you got *buff, but because buff is defined as a char array, I'd use buff[0] for cleanliness.  If we had an additional char *bufp = buff, I'd go with *bufp (or bufp[0])